# Scalaz ValidationNel - folding

Tags: scala, validation, nested, scalaz, fold

I've recently used ScalaZ for validation purposes and decided to choose ValidationNel as a fail fast behavior wasn't desired. I had more than 12 validation checks to make, thus I couldn't use operator |@| so I've expressed it with <*> like that:

```
validatePropertyA(object.propertyA) <*>
  (validatePropertyB(object.propertyB) <*>
    (validatePropertyC(object.propertyC) map (_ => _ => _ => object)))
```

Having about 15 properties to check, this code becomes rather complicated and looks at the first glance like something which could be expressed with foldRight instead, but I don't have a clue how to achieve this.

Is foldRight feasible for the job of making this chunk of code concise or do I have to use something else?

Answer (score 1):

You could easily do this using `traverse` or `sequence`:

```
List(validatePropertyA(object.propertyA), validatePropertyB(object.propertyB), ...)
  .sequence.map(_ => object)
```

That will give you back a `Validated` with all the errors on the left side and the `object` on the right side.

Comment: Shouldn't `sequence` take any arguments here?

Comment: @Hooberd `.sequence` is essentially `.traverse(identity)`, so it doesn't take any arguments

Comment: @GabrielePetronella when I try to call .sequence on a list of Validations or ValidationNels I get `Error:(12, 43) not enough arguments for method sequence: (implicit ev: scalaz.Leibniz.===[scalaz.Validation[Int,Int],G[B]], implicit G: scalaz.Applicative[G])G[List[B]].
Unspecified value parameters ev, G.
    val list = List(1.success, 2.failure).sequence` - what am I missing here?

Comment: I've haven't used Scalaz in a while, but can you try `sequenceU` instead of `sequence`?